# Creating a software synth with dynamically created dom elements and a variable that I can't seem to pass

Tags: javascript, dom, web-audio-api

Here is a JSfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ZttnJ/5/

The issue is I simply need a variable in one scope accessible to another, but if I put the variable in a higher scope it breaks the dynamic creation of the element.This seems like something that would be a reoccurring issue with dynamically created dom elements and I am very curious if there is a boiler plate way to solve this without recreating the code into constructors with prototypes or something. I commented the code for clarity. There is only one comment.

```
var SynthCreationModule = (function(){


context = new webkitAudioContext(); 
var orangeButton;
var applicationArea = document.getElementById("applicationArea"),
orangeButton = document.getElementById("orangeButton"),         
counterSynth = 1;
counterSynthMuteButton = 1;
counterSynthParameters = 1;
counterPitchInput = 1;
orangeButton.addEventListener("click",createSynth, false);     



function createSynth () {
    var pitchInput = document.createElement('input').value; // I need this to be accessible to the function called synth.onmousedown
    pitchInput.type = "range";
    pitchInput.className  = "pitchInputClass";
    pitchInput.id = "pitchInput" + (counterPitchInput++);   
    var synth = document.createElement("div"); 
    synth.className  = "synth";                        
    synth.id = "synth" + (counterSynth++);
    var synthMute = document.createElement("div");
    synthMute.className  = "synthMute";   
    synthMute.id = "synthMute" + (counterSynthMuteButton++);
    applicationArea.appendChild(synth);
    synth.appendChild(synthMute);
    synth.appendChild(pitchInput);
    $(synth).draggable({ snap: true });
    $(synth).draggable({ grid: [ 20,20 ]});



    synth.onmousedown= function () {
    oscillator = context.createOscillator(), 
    oscillator.type = 2;  
    oscillator.frequency.value = pitchInput;                   
    oscillator.connect(context.destination);  
    oscillator.noteOn(0); 


    };

    synth.onmouseup = function ()    {  
    oscillator.disconnect(); 

    };
```

Comment: Your code sample formatting is confusing. The indentation is broken and there's at least one `}` missing that's essential to knowing how your scopes are set up.

Comment: Also, please only include relevant code in samples. Near as I can tell, there's only two lines of code in the above that have anything to do with your question.

Comment: Ok, I'll reformat. I though comment would clarify

Comment: You're mixing native DOM selection methods (`document.getElementById`) with equivalent jQuery selectors (`$("#orangeButton")`). I also see three different ways to bind an event handler (`.addEventListener(...)`, `.onmousedown = ...`, `$.click(...)`). I suggest a thorough cleanup before you start messing with it any further.

Comment: @Taoist: You added even more mostly irrelevant code and haven't fixed the one problem that I pointed out. My point is: do not make us work with *all* your code. Reduce your problem to *only* the code that *directly* causes it, and make that your entire code sample, and make that parse correctly, and make it pretty. This goes for jsFiddle as well.

Comment: Maybe you can find a way to access the created DOM element by ID or class? Then you don't have to worry about passing variables between scopes.

Comment: @millimoose. It's a synth that has audio, dynamic dom element creation and slider elements connected. I think I simply need to re title the post. The code isn't irrelevant to insuring the whole thing works in it's entirety.If I only post two functions and ask how to get one variable to another the answer is easy - global. But in the context of my project that doesn't work, hence the problem :)

Comment: @Taoist "the answer is easy - global". That is *not* the answer. **Scope your variables!** As much as you can, keep them out of the global scope unless you absolutely *want* to expose them to the outside. On another note, to use the *value* of `pitchInput` as frequency value, you should be using `oscillator.frequency.value = pitchInput.value;` (and not just `= pitchInput`, that doesn't make any sense).

Comment: Ok, I meant an outer scope. I said "global" to quickly make my more substantive point that the entire block is connected.My point was the entire block is connected. I got rid of some jquery code but kept the sliding elements assuming it would help give an understanding of how it works if used in the JSfiddle example

Comment: @Taoist Good, you almost gave me a heart attack there! Now, try to refactor your code. I suggest you make more use of the potential of jQuery, more specifically get rid of the explicit `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` assignments and start using `$.on('mousedown')` and `$.on('mouseup')`.

Comment: I really try and stay away from JQuery as much as possible because I want to know raw javascript as much as possible. I only use JQuery as an addendum to javascript for effects etc. Eventually I'll go that route but not at the moment.

Comment: @Taoist Then go all the way and get rid of jQuery from that script (maybe apart from that `draggable` thingy, since implementing drag-and-drop from scratch is though). You can use `addEventListener` to register the `click`, `mousedown` and `mouseup` events and access the scoped variables from the registered handler. Also, get rid of those random IDs, you don't need them.

Comment: @Taoist "How to make my codebase work in its entirety?" is a question that should be closed summarily. Don't ask that question, if only because people by and large won't want to answer it. Another reason why you're asked to isolate your problem to the basics is that doing so is a great way to find out the solution. Also, sticking to raw Javascript is somewhat insane, mostly because the DOM is insane. (Unless you really want to learn about obscure browser incompatibilities the hard way; but chances are you just want to make stuff work, and crowdsourcing that effort simply makes sense.)

Comment: @Taoist Another reason why you want to isolate your problems is that otherwise you risk people picking on random tangential issues in your code like say your inconsistent use of DOM APIs instead of tackling the issue you're actually having a problem with that's buried under the rest. Also, the idea wasn't to write dummy functions that show *a problem* - it was reducing your specific problem to its core. Just deleting all the lines of code where the variable you need to share isn't even being used would be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to modify the above code like this:

```
function createSynth () {

    var pitchInput = document.createElement('input');
    pitchInput.type = "range";
    pitchInput.className  = "pitchInputClass";
    pitchInput.id = "pitchInput" + (counterPitchInput++);  
    var synth = document.createElement("div"); 
    synth.className  = "synth";                          
    synth.id = "synth" + (counterSynth++);

    var synthMute = document.createElement("div");
    synthMute.className  = "synthMute";   
    synthMute.id = "synthMute" + (counterSynthMuteButton++);
    applicationArea.appendChild(synth);
    synth.appendChild(synthMute);
    synth.appendChild(pitchInput);
    $(synth).draggable({ snap: true });
    $(synth).draggable({ grid: [ 20,20 ]});


  synth.addEventListener("mousedown",playSynth, false);

function playSynth() {
//var pitchState = document.getElementById('oscPitch1').value;
oscillator = context.createOscillator(),  // Creates the oscillator 
oscillator.type = 2;  
oscillator.frequency.value = pitchInput.value;                   
oscillator.connect(context.destination);  // Connects it to output
oscillator.noteOn(0); 


};
```

Comment: It doesn't let me immediately. I still need to wait another 17 hours. :)

Comment: Ah, didn't know that :) Sorry!